# Java Optional Parametrized Interfaces

Tags: java, interface, java-8, abstract, parameterized-types

I have an interface like so:

```
public interface Foo<T> {
    default void doStuff(T val1, T val2) {}

    default void doStuff(T val) {}
}
```

The idea behind the interface being you can implement either one or the other methods. So then I have an abstract class like so:

```
abstract public class AbstractFoo<T> implements Foo<T> {
    //Bunch of Stuff
}
```

And finally an implementation like so:

```
public class AwesomeOne extends AbstractFoo<String> {
    @Override
    public void doStuff(String val) {
        //Do Stuff
    }
}
```

Here's an example of another implementation:

```
public class AwesomeTwo extends AbstractFoo<String> {
    @Override
    public void doStuff(String val1, String val2) {
        //Do Stuff
    }
}
```

This works just fine. Now, I want to be able to specify 2 different types for the `doStuff(val1, val2)` method. So I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
public class AwesomeThree extends AbstractFoo<String, Double> {
    @Override
    public void doStuff(String val1, Double val2) {
        //Do Stuff
    }
}
```

This is how my interface would change:

```
public interface Foo<S, T> {
    default void doStuff(S val1, T val2) {}

    default void doStuff(T val) {}
}
```

But I am having difficulty getting the abstract class to work with this. Because while I can change my abstract class to this:

```
abstract public class AbstractFoo<S, T> implements Foo<S, T> {
    //Bunch of Stuff
}
```

That would change implementation classes like so:

```
public class AwesomeOne extends AbstractFoo<Object, String> {
    @Override
    public void doStuff(String val) {
        //Do Stuff
    }
}
```

Which works but....that's not really a clean solution. Also it would cause me to refactor all the existing implementations.

Basically in plain English I want to say:

> When implementing the Foo interface, you can implement either of the 2
>   methods specified in the interface. If you are implementing the single
>   parameter method, doStuff(T val), you only need to specify 1
>   parametrized type. If, however, you are implementing the double
>   parameter method, doStuff(S val1, T val2), you have to specify both
>   parameterized types.

Is this possible in Java and if so what is the cleanest approach to this problem?

Comment: The point of an interface is to implement _every_ method.  Your design violates the Liskov Substitution Principle; how could you ever call through the interface?

Comment: default methods in an interface usually have a coded body,

Comment: Your "plain english description" does a good point explaining your situation. Within this description you have two cases (either the one or the other method). Split those cases into two separate interfaces. This should also preservie the Liskov Substitution Principle.

Comment: You should try to describe what you are trying to achieve not how you're trying to achieve it. It seems like you already created the solution frame for your problem but it just doesn't fit, so now you're trying to bend it.

Comment: Your question is an [X/Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Tell us what problem you are trying to solve instead of asking for help with the solution, which does not appear to be the correct approach.

Comment: *The idea behind the interface being you can implement either one or the other methods.* you have to implement **all** methods in an `interface` in Java, there is no getting around that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are violating some of the OO principles, which is why the design doesn't feel clean.

Your specification that an implementation must do "this or that" smells like a violation of the *interface segregation* principle to me. That's the "I" of the SOLID principles.

So to fix this, we want to represent the operation with an abstraction:

```
public interface StuffDoer {
  void run();
}
```

Cool. That's easy. So now you want a 1-arg stuff doer and a 2-arg stuff doer. But every `StuffDoer` must be able to `run`(). See? Just one mandatory method now.

```
public abstract class OneArgStuffDoer<T1> implements StuffDoer {
  private final T1 arg;
  public OneArgStuffDoer(T1 arg) {
    this.arg = Objects.requireNonNull(arg);
  }
  public final void run() {
    run(arg);
  }
  abstract void run(T1 arg);
}
```

You can play a similar game with `TwoArgStuffDoer`. Now your API to implementations will be to extend either `OneArgStuffDoer` or `TwoArgStuffDoer`, and implement either `run(T1 arg)` from the former or `run(T1 arg1, T2 arg2)` from that latter.

Here's what `AwesomeOne` would look like:

```
public final class AwesomeOne extends OneArgStuffDoer<String> {
  @Override
  void run(String str) { // do your awesome stuff here }
}
```

Nice and clean! Right!?!

Hope that helps!

Comment: Please be careful with your code examples. It seemed compilable, but isn't due to the illegal identifier `do`. I changed occurances of `do()` to `run()` to allow compilation (feel free to change if you dislike my naming choice). I have also added some text formatting for types. I recommended adding links to buzzwords (like interface segregation & SOLID) to attract more views and votes.

Comment: @Vince Thanks! Good catch. I didn't type it up in an IDE  and didn't think about it.